# dom4j XPath not node-type

Tags: java, xpath, dom4j

I try to get just a part of an attribute (could also be a part of an element), but no luck so far. The exception I get is "Invalid XPath expression: //@att/tokenize(., ' ')[.][position() = 1] Expected node-type". I'm using dom4j 1.6.1.

```
import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
import org.dom4j.XPath;
import org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath;


public class TestXPathString {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws DocumentException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {
        Document doc = DocumentHelper
                .parseText("<x><y att='I just need the first word' /></x>");
        XPath xpath = new DefaultXPath("//@att/tokenize(., ' ')[.][position() = 1]");
        Object result = xpath.evaluate(doc);
        System.out.printf("Type: %s, Value: %s\n", result.getClass()
                .getSimpleName(), result);
    }

}
```

It doesn't work with

```
doc.selectObject("//@att/substring-before(., ' ')");
```

either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying functions in axis steps is an XPath 2.0 feature; Java (and dom4j) only support XPath 1.0. You cannot do this.

If you only expect a single result, use `substring-before(//@att, ' ')`. Otherwise, pass the whole attribute value to Java and do the string manipulation outside XPath.

You might consider plugging a more powerful XPath/XQuery engine, like Saxon, BaseX or other native XML databases with Java APIs available.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification. Indeed, the "substring-before" example is working. However, it looks as if I need the tokenize function as I also want a return value if the attribute contains just one word. "substring-before()" returns nothing if the separator is not found at all.

Comment: `tokenize` is another XPath 2.0 function. ;)

Comment: Yes, I know. Just wanted to point out the obvious that I definitely have to use something supporting XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
//*/substring-before(@att, ' ')
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I get the same error though: Invalid XPath expression: //*/substring-before(@att, ' ') Expected node-type

Comment: This shares exactly the same problem with the original query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Saxon XPath 2.0 engine to query DOM4J. Your expression will then work.